# Invalid component name: "pages/product/_slug.vue". Component names should conform to valid custom element name in html5 specification

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-router, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt.js and have some dynamic routes. My folder structure is this:

```
- pages
 - product
  - _slug.vue
```

I link to the route like this:

```
<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'product-slug', params: { slug: product.slug } }">
```

It works fine, it shows the correct URL and also directs the page fine, however, I am getting an annoying red error in my console:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid component name: "pages/product/_slug.vue". Component names should conform to valid custom element name in html5 specification.
```

[image]

I have found this issue, but to little avail: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/165

Comment: have you tried `<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'product/slug', params: { slug: product.slug } }">` ?

Answer (score 13):

Where you have name in your component remove the space between the name. e.g

```
export default {
  name: 'Assign Role'
}
```

Change it to:

```
export default {
  name: 'AssignRole',
}
```

Comment: or add it if you don't have an export from that file

Comment: He was correct. When you do NOT specify a "name" in the component, Nuxt assigns the path as the name.

You need to add: `export default { name: 'componentName', ... }` to fix the warning.

Answer (score 6):

The reason of this error message is that the name of the `_slug.vue` component which is the same as the file name.

I expect it `name='_slug.vue'` you need to change it to something like this `name='ProductItem'`

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure this is a bug or what.

But after giving a name to my components, fixed this issue as follows.

```
  export default {
    name: 'NameOfTheCompnent',
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vue 2.x with `vue-property-decorator` it can get this problem when class of vue component looks like:

```js
@Component({})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
...
}
```

You should remove `({})` or set specific value for the `name` field -  `@Component` or `@Component({ name: 'MyComponent' })`.